# Code stops working when I change the EventListener from "click" to "keydown"

Tags: addeventlistener, keydown, onkeydown

The piece of code below sucessfully manages to change the position of a block within a grid when you click on it ( on the grid ).

However , I intend to do it when I press on a key. It happens that when I change the EventListener from "click" to "keydown" I get no response if I press on any key of my laptop while running the script.

I assume something is wrong with the element (I need to focus it? How ?) , or the document somehow is unable to recognize the key input. What can I do to try fix this problem ?

```
let x = 5;
let y = 5;

function CreateSnake(){
  tabuleiro.appendChild(snake);
   snake.style.gridColumnStart = x;
   snake.style.gridRowStart = y;

   snake.classList.add("snake");
  };

  tabuleiro.addEventListener("click" , function(){
      moveSnakeRight();
      remove()
    });

function moveSnakeRight(){
  if ( x < 10)
  console.log(x++)
;
}

function remove(){
  snake.remove()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you've got the `keydown` event listener on the wrong element. In order to handle the `keydown` event, the element must be able to receive focus (setting `tabindex`). See the following demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mqe59dL6/

```js
const noFocus = document.getElementById('noFocus');
const focus = document.getElementById('focus');

function handler(event) {
    event.cancelBubble = true;
    console.log(event.target.id || 'document', event.keyCode);
}

noFocus.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
focus.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
document.addEventListener('keydown', handler);
```

```css
#noFocus {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #aff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#focus {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #faf;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="noFocus">
  I can't receive focus. Events will go to the document.
</div>
<div id="focus" tabindex="0">
  I can receive focus, click on me first.
</div>
```

An alternative is to handle the event on the `document` instead. Try `document.addEventListener("keydown", ...)`.

Comment: Maybe could it be the fact that element is not a form which you can "select" ??

Comment: What kind of element is `tabuleiro`? In order to respond to `keydown`, the element needs to be able to receive focus. See the following demo: https://jsfiddle.net/mqe59dL6/

Comment: The problem is definitely a ``` :focus ```` problem. 

Once I set the tabindex to 0 and select the grid with a mousclick, the keydown starts working !